# PostgreSQL - dump file and database rules

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump, rules

I have problem with dump files generated by pg_dump for PostgresSQL database. I have table with database rules (these rules have references to other tables). When I create dump file using pg_dump, these rules are added to dump file. Is it possible to skip this rules when create dump file or is it possible to skip them when I restore table?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I would look at deleting them from the dump file, if it is a textual dump.  This could be done with a simple Perl, rebol, or sed script.  I don't think there is a way to just not dump rules (or triggers, or functions) but you can remove them before reloading.